# Understanding how WCF works

Tags: silverlight, wcf, nhibernate, dto

I am using a WCF service between the Client side UI (Silverlight 3.0) and the Data Layer. We are using NHibernate for Database Access. So please tell me if my below understanding is correct or not:

- UI calls WCF for a Save Method (for eg).
- The WCF has a Save method in it which actually encapsulates a Save method from the Data 
  Access Object.
- The Data Access Object method of Save in turn encapsulates a default Save Method of 
  NHibernate which actually saves some Business Object/s into the Database.

Also can someone tell me that how do we pass objects from WCF to the UI (Silverlight 3.0) layer and vice versa. I have read that we use DTO for that. But how does a DTO work? Do they correspond to the 'Data Contracts' in the WCF? If not then is the DTO declared on WCF (server) side and Client side code as well?

Comment: Thanks a lot for reminding me the rules. And sorry for not following them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not quite....

- UI calls the client-side proxy method `Save`
- the WCF runtime takes that call and all parameters being passed in, and serializes them into a message (typically a XML serialized message)
- the WCF runtime sends the serialized message over some kind of a transport media (whatever it is)
- on the server side, the WCF runtime takes the incoming message
- the message is deserialized, the appropriate class and method to handle it are identified
- typically: a new instance of a service class is instantiated to handle the request
- the WCF runtime unpacks the parameters and calls that appropriate message on the service class
- same steps - basically backwards - are done for response

Important point: the **only thing** between the client and the server is a **serialized message** (which could be sent by e-mail or pigeon courier) - there's **no other connection** - no "remote object call" or anything like that at all

Comment: I got the concept of messages in XML being passed while using WCF. My understanding is that if we want to pass the values of the Employee object to the UI from the WCF, then we declare Employee as Data Contract and pass the values to and from the WCF. If I am wrong then please correct. Also if this is the case then is the Employee class here in some ways represent a DTO?

Comment: @tahoka: you're absolutely correct. A DataContract describes how a CLR object will be serialized into a message. And yes - those object typically are data-transfer objects - just properties, no functionality

Answer (score 1):

marc_s mentions the client-side proxies, which can be generated via the [service references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197937%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in your Silverlight project. The generated proxies are decent enough and provide an async model for running requests from the Silverlight side; those will look mostly like remoted procedure calls.

Another approach is to use the leaner (but maybe more advanced?) channel factory directly. A simple example of that can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681.aspx). Both methods take care of most of the serialization details for you.

Comment: Good point - but the basic premise doesn't change - WCF still exchanges nothing but serialized messages, there's no "remote object" connection of any kind...

Comment: Completely agree. I upped your description of the exchange, might actually use it in conversation (with disclaimer!). In my post I was trying to add how to get that exchange to work.